# Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'multiselectfield'

Tags: django, django-models

Just like the heading says. Everything works when I run the server locally but when I deploy i get this error.  First time posting and I am very new to Django. I have re installed multiselectfield using pip3 and I have checked the version. I have also run pip freeze to check all the packages and I can see that multiselectfield is there. I checked my migrations and i can see it added to the database.

```
 File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'multiselectfield'


from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from phone_field import PhoneField
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField
import datetime
WEEKS = (
    ('1', 'Week 1'),
    ('2', 'Week 2'),
    ('3', 'Week 3'),
    ('4', 'Week 4'),
    ('5', 'Week 5'),
    ('6', 'Week 6'),
    ('7', 'Week 7'),
    ('8', 'Week 8'),
    ('9', 'Week 9'),
    ('10', 'Week 10'),
    ('11', 'Week 11'),
)

# Create your models here.
class Parent(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = PhoneField(blank=True,E164_only=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('parent_details',kwargs={'parent_id': self.id})

class Summer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    child_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    week_number = MultiSelectField(
        choices = WEEKS,
        default = 1
        )
    phone = PhoneField(blank=True,E164_only=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('summer_details', kwargs={'summer_id': self.id})
import os
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

BASE_URL = 'https://www.sdkidzkamp.com'


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.sdkidzkamp.com', 'sdkidzkamp.com']


# GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_MODEL = True

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # 'google_analytics',
    
    'phone_field',
    'bootstrap5',
    'crispy_forms',
    'main_app',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'multiselectfield',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True

ROOT_URLCONF = 'kidzkamp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'kidzkamp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'kidzkamp',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Comment: I just to have a similar issue, I was using pipenv for my virtual environment, so when I installed a package I had to "pipenv install...." not just pip install

Comment: I didn't have to use pipenv for any other packages. Whats weird is that when i run pip freeze I can see the package properly installed